# AVPlayer frame precision

Tags: ios, avplayer, frame-rate

Goal : During playback of a movie must be carried out actions with precise timing.

I use for that an AVPlayer with a PeriodicTimeOberver with a CTimeMake(1000,25000).
My movie framerate is 25fps.

But it's not precise.
It trigger a lot of time without reason ( see here : [IOS addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval fire too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401206/ios-addperiodictimeobserverforinterval-fire-too-many-times))
addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval give me the same problems.

I know only CTime functions. 
There is someway to trigger an event at 2 seconds and 2 frames (52th frame).

Thanks in advance.
Daniele